# How many bit strings of length 15 have exactly three 0s?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, education

I need help with this question: How many bit strings of length 15 have exactly three 0s?

Comment: Hint:  How many ways are there to **choose** $3$ places from the $15$ for the $0$'s to go?

Comment: For the OP: Since you are new here, my suggestion is that you try to phrase a question about the math you are having trouble with. Think of it as akin to asking help from a math teacher -- you would not merely restate the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are 15 ways to put the first zero, fourteen (since one spot already has a zero) ways to put the second zero, and thirteen ways to put the third zero.

The zeroes all look the same, so you then have to divide by the number of ways the three could be ordered (which is 3! for the 3 zeroes, or 6)

So, the number of ways to do it is 15*14*13/6